# Scatter plot with bar legend

Tags: graphics, legending

I have two data sets:

```
xy = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, ...}
z = {z1, z2, ...}
```

I want to plot at each `(xi, yi)` a point in a two dimensional plane, but color coded according to the value of `zi`. Next to the plot I want a `BarLegend` with blue corresponding to the smallest `z` value and red corresponding to the largest `z` value.

I already have some code, but I think the Legend is still missing. Of course other more simpler solutions are also welcome.

```
 colorf = Blend[{{Min[z], Blue}, {Max[z], Red}}, #] &
 pl = 
   Graphics[MapThread[{colorf[#1], Point[#2]} &, {z, xy}], 
     Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, 
     AxesLabel -> {OverTilde["x"], OverTilde["y"]}]
```

Comment: If you can tell me how to introduce a title in the legend then I agree!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xy = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {5000, 2}];
z = RandomReal[1, 5000];
colorf = Blend[{{Min[z], Blue}, {Max[z], Red}}, #] &;

pl = Graphics[MapThread[{colorf@#, Point@#2} &, {z, xy}], AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True];
barlegend = BarLegend[{colorf, Through[{Min, Max}@z]}, 10, 
   LegendMarkerSize -> 300, LegendLabel -> Style["legend", 16, "Panel"]];

Legended[pl, barlegend]
```

[image]